# Is type info automatically updated prior calling destructor

Tags: c++

I know that virtual table is automatically updated prior calling class destructor, so I came on mind to check what happens with the object type information. I wrote this example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base(std::function<void(Base*)> callback) : _callback(callback) {}

    virtual ~Base() {
        _callback(this);
    }

    std::function<void(Base*)> _callback;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    using Base::Base;
};
int main() {
    auto check_type = [](Base* item) {
        if (dynamic_cast<Derived*>(item)) {
            std::cout << "is derived" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "no derived" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    Derived derived(check_type);
    check_type(&derived);

    return 0;
}
```

and based on the output:

```
is derived
no derived
```

seems that clang-802.0.41 updates this record. Now i want to know if this is standardised or it is compiler specific ?

Answer (score 3):

That use of [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) does not work in constructors or destructors. During `Base::Base` you have not executed the derived type's constructor you. Similarly, by the time you get to `Base::~Base` the derived type's destructor must have finished. In both cases your instance is not a valid `Derived` object yet.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast#Explanation

> 6) When dynamic_cast is used in a constructor or a destructor (directly or indirectly), and expression refers to the object that's currently under construction/destruction, the object is considered to be the most derived object. **If new_type is not a pointer or reference to the constructor's/destructor's own class or one of its bases, the behavior is undefined.**

Answer (score 0):

In [class.cdtor 15.7](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor):

> If the operand of the dynamic_­cast refers to the object under
>   construction or destruction and the static type of the operand is not
>   a pointer to or object of the constructor or destructor's own class or
>   one of its bases, the dynamic_­cast results in undefined behavior.

`this` is not a pointer to `Base`'s own class nor one of its bases so you have undefined behaviour.